How can I print to a thermal printer XP-80C in a MERN stack environment
I have tried a number of library, some do not even install with npm install especially printer and electron. Other Libraries I was able to either throws an internal error that is not from my code or they work in development and fail in the production server render Below is what I currently have with electron-pos-printer, please any modification or suggestion with the kind of environment I have will be appreciated alot! Thanks
const { PosPrinter } = require("electron-pos-printer");
const path = require("path");


async function printReceipt(data) {
  try {
    const options = {
      preview: false,
      margin: "0 0 0 0",
      copies: 1,
      printerName: "XP-80C",
      timeOutPerLine: 400,
      pageSize: { width: 80, height: 297 },
      silent: true,
    };

    const {
      items,
    } = data;

    const receiptData = 
      {
        type: "text",
        value: items.length,
        style: `text-align:center;`,
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        value: "\n\n\n",
      },
      // other data
    ];

    PosPrinter.print(receiptData, options)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("Failed to print receipt");
  }
}

module.exports = {
  printReceipt,
};

This particular code gives the error below:
throw new Error(error.message);       
              ^

Error: r.BrowserWindow is not a constructor   
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\coding\Inventory\inventory-app\utils\printReceipt.js:200:15   
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.20.4

If you have any other suggestion that I can use as a replacement for this for the MERN stack environment, it will be much appreciated!

electron is a framework for making desktop apps. electron-pos-printer uses it, and by extension Chromium's rendering and printing functionality, to print. It's not going to work in an Express(-only) environment. Without more details (errors, whether or not you installed all dependencies, etc) nobody can answer why the other packages you tried failed.

Thank you so much for your comment about this. Kindly, what can you recommend, I could pay if you can help me with this functionality in the environment I have, I have been on it for a while, I am just tired of trying and downloading libraries upon libraries @RickN
